# Possible to block (or send own html instead of) a website in android? [Noroot]

Tags: java, android, networking

Is it possible to block a website by url or send a custom response with html like "This page is blocked" in android/java? I want to use it systemwide (Also in the drfault web browser). The phoe for which I build the app has no root? Is there a way to realise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a VpnService. For example see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/06/android-vpn-service/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please post an example for me? (I am new to android development and java). It is also important that i can access other devices in my wifi network.

Comment: I've posted a tutorial with example in my answer. You can also look here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn/src/com/example/android/toyvpn/

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I read the tutorial and the android code. But i can't really figure out how to realize a blacklist. Could you post a blacklist example in your answer please? Then i will accept and upvote your answer. Thank you very much ;-)

Comment: After you reconstruct packets transport and application layers data, you can filter by content of UDP or HTTP requests. It's not a simple task, but your request is not simple either. I can't write this code for you, but you can start and I will try to help you in any follow up questions :)